# Switching from Windows 10 to Ubuntu, What should I backup before hand?

Tags: software-installation, windows, backup

So I have 2 drives on my computer, C: and D:, I have windows installed on my C: drive so should I backup both the C: and D: Drives? or just C:? Furthermore, what do I do with the Windows that is installed on the C: drive? I can't just wipe the drive cause I have files on it.

after the backup(s) are done, what do I do? is there a built in feature that lets me just put the files to Ubuntu?

Thanks
~ Matthew.

Comment: Keep Windows, for BIOS updates, and Windows programs for which there is no Ubuntu compatible app, and install Ubuntu in a dual-boot configuration. Assuming that your D: drive is NTFS, put any docs/videos/music/pictures there, and Ubuntu can r/w with NTFS. That way you can access them from both Windows and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should have backups of everything whether you are switching to Linux or not.  Certainly, if you are going to install Linux, I would suggesting backing up both drives as disk images so that everything is recoverable should something go south.

Assuming that your C: drive is fairly large (practically speaking, you probably need around 10 GB of free space for a useful Linux system, although you can certainly get by with less), I would suggest installing Linux in dual boot mode (some installers call this side-by-side or alongside).  This means assigning some of the free space on the current hard disk as a separate partition on which Linux is installed.  This gives you a boot menu from which you can select either Windows or Linux.  Subsequently, in Linux, you can mount either or both of the Windows drives and access the files.

In my view this gives you the best of all worlds.  You have a solid backup, you can use either Windows or Linux, and you can use the same data files in both operating systems.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So with this dual boot mode, can I access files from both the C: and D: drives from either system? and I have 40gb left on my C: drive, should I allocate all of it to Linux or just the 10gb you previously stated?

Comment: 10 Gigs is sufficient to install and view Ubuntu.  But it's hardly enough for really using it.  It's hardly enough for being really productive with any OS.  I would recommend that you allocate as much space as you can.  There are lots of applications you can run.  A lot of people think of their computers for something to play with.  While you can have fun with it, there's so much more you can do with the computer.  You can collect and catalog favorite events of personal pictures and videos.  You can install applications to edit your media... ran out of comment spac

Comment: I have to put Ubuntu on the same drive as Windows(C: SSD)? because if I really need to allocate more room for Ubuntu than I can use my bigger, albeit slower, HHD D:?

Comment: I concur with L.D. James.  If you aren't using 40GB on your C: drive, then use this space for Linux.  You can access the Windows partitions of both the C: and D: drives by mounting them at bootup.  Add entries to the /etc/fstab file as indicated in https://linuxnorth.wordpress.com/2011/02/20/mounting-disks-automatically/